# Package SVG animate in Beamer does not animate

Tags: beamer, linux, animations, animate, svg

I recently discovered that I can use the `dvisvgm` engine to work in SVG presentations and have them play in my browser. So I found this new package `animate` [here](https://gitlab.com/agrahn/animate) and I am attempting to have my own animations. But at least the doc of the PDF show the figures and everything, but no animations. I am using Chrome or Brave on a Fedora 31.

For example, I am attempting to reproduce the first example in the documentation (at p17 as of the doc version of 05.29.20), except that I get rid of the `timeline` option because I cannot quickly figure out how to generate a `timeline.txt` file (and the one used in the docs are not included in files).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{filecontents}{timeline.txt}
::0x0 % coordinate system & y=e^x, repeated until last frame
::1 % one blue curve per frame
::2
::3
::4
::5
::6
::7
::8
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\animategraphics[label=taylor,
                 controls, loop,
                ]{4}{exp_}{0}{8}
\mediabutton[jsaction={if(anim[’taylor’].isPlaying)anim[’taylor’].pause();else anim[’taylor’].playFwd();}
]{\fbox{Play/Pause}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I tried to get use `dvisvgm` option either as optional argument of `documentclass` or of `animate`, and neither worked -- in the second case, the option is not recognized.

This is the error flow from the log file.

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2018)  (format=lualatex 2020.6.6)  7 JUN 2020 10:35
 restricted system commands enabled.
**animate_example.tex
(./animate_example.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2017/01/29 2.80001 OpenType layout system.
Lua module: lualibs 2017-02-01 2.5 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2017-02-01 2.5 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended co
llection.(using write cache: /home/maurizio/.texlive2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/
generic)(using read cache: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic /ho
me/maurizio/.texlive2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is /home/maurizio/.texlive2018/texmf-va
r/luatex-cache/generic/names.
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader “fontloader-2017-02-11.lua” from kpse
-resolved path “/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader
-2017-02-11.lua”.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@state = 1
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 2
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@syllabe = 3
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version “3.027”
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 4
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is /home/maurizio/.texlive2018/texmf-va
r/luatex-cache/generic/names.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
.
luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.159 seconds
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from /home/maurizio/.texlive2018/te
xmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc(load luc: /home/maurizio
/.texlive2018/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman10-regular.luc))
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (/home/maurizio/texmf/tex/latex/animate/animate.sty
Package: animate 2020/05/29 PDF & SVG animations from files and inline graphics

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks14
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks15

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count88
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2013/04/04 v0.2 Provides if(tex) conditional for PDFTeX, XeTeX, a
nd LuaTeX
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/ifdraft.sty
Package: ifdraft 2016/05/16 v1.4 Detect class options draft and final (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
Package: calc 2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count89
\calc@Bcount=\count90
\calc@Adimen=\dimen103
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen104
\calc@Askip=\skip43
\calc@Bskip=\skip44
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count91
\calc@Cskip=\skip45
)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.33 \ifpdf
         \else
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Extra \else.
l.33 \ifpdf\else

I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.

! Extra \fi.
l.57 \fi

I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.60 \ifxetex

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Extra \fi.
l.64 \fi

I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: dvisvgm.def on input line 99.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvisvgm.def
File: dvisvgm.def 2017/06/20 v1.0b dvisvgm graphics driver for latex
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-abspage.sty
Package: zref-abspage 2016/05/21 v2.26 Module abspage for zref (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-base.sty
Package: zref-base 2016/05/21 v2.26 Module base for zref (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX detected.
)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2018/01/30 v0.27 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)


(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
\pdftexcmds@toks=\toks16
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
Package zref Info: New property list: main on input line 759.
Package zref Info: New property: default on input line 760.
Package zref Info: New property: page on input line 761.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/atbegshi.sty
Package: atbegshi 2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
)
\c@abspage=\count92
Package zref Info: New property: abspage on input line 62.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/media9/pdfbase.sty
(/home/maurizio/texmf/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2020-06-03 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/home/maurizio/texmf/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
Package: expl3 2020-06-03 L3 programming layer (code)
\c_max_int=\count93
\l_tmpa_int=\count94
\l_tmpb_int=\count95
\g_tmpa_int=\count96
\g_tmpb_int=\count97
\l__seq_internal_a_int=\count98
\l__seq_internal_b_int=\count99
\g__kernel_prg_map_int=\count100
\c__ior_term_noprompt_ior=\count101
\c_log_iow=\count102
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count103
\l__iow_line_target_int=\count104
\l__iow_one_indent_int=\count105
\l__iow_indent_int=\count106
\c_zero_dim=\dimen105
\c_max_dim=\dimen106
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen107
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen108
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen109
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen110
\c_zero_skip=\skip46
\c_max_skip=\skip47
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip48
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip49
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip50
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip51
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
\l_keys_choice_int=\count107
\l__intarray_loop_int=\count108
\c__intarray_sp_dim=\dimen111
\g__intarray_font_int=\count109
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count110
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count111
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count112
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count113
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count114
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count115
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count116
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count117
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count118
\g__fp_array_int=\count119
\l__fp_array_loop_int=\count120
\l__sort_length_int=\count121
\l__sort_min_int=\count122
\l__sort_top_int=\count123
\l__sort_max_int=\count124
\l__sort_true_max_int=\count125
\l__sort_block_int=\count126
\l__sort_begin_int=\count127
\l__sort_end_int=\count128
\l__sort_A_int=\count129
\l__sort_B_int=\count130
\l__sort_C_int=\count131
\l__str_internal_int=\count132
\l__tl_analysis_normal_int=\count133
\l__tl_analysis_index_int=\count134
\l__tl_analysis_nesting_int=\count135
\l__tl_analysis_type_int=\count136
\l__regex_internal_a_int=\count137
\l__regex_internal_b_int=\count138
\l__regex_internal_c_int=\count139
\l__regex_balance_int=\count140
\l__regex_group_level_int=\count141
\l__regex_mode_int=\count142
\c__regex_cs_in_class_mode_int=\count143
\c__regex_cs_mode_int=\count144
\l__regex_catcodes_int=\count145
\l__regex_default_catcodes_int=\count146
\c__regex_catcode_L_int=\count147
\c__regex_catcode_O_int=\count148
\c__regex_catcode_A_int=\count149
\c__regex_all_catcodes_int=\count150
\l__regex_show_lines_int=\count151
\l__regex_min_state_int=\count152
\l__regex_max_state_int=\count153
\l__regex_left_state_int=\count154
\l__regex_right_state_int=\count155
\l__regex_capturing_group_int=\count156
\l__regex_min_pos_int=\count157
\l__regex_max_pos_int=\count158
\l__regex_curr_pos_int=\count159
\l__regex_start_pos_int=\count160
\l__regex_success_pos_int=\count161
\l__regex_curr_char_int=\count162
\l__regex_curr_catcode_int=\count163
\l__regex_last_char_int=\count164
\l__regex_case_changed_char_int=\count165
\l__regex_curr_state_int=\count166
\l__regex_step_int=\count167
\l__regex_min_active_int=\count168
\l__regex_max_active_int=\count169
\l__regex_replacement_csnames_int=\count170
\l__regex_match_count_int=\count171
\l__regex_min_submatch_int=\count172
\l__regex_submatch_int=\count173
\l__regex_zeroth_submatch_int=\count174
\g__regex_trace_regex_int=\count175
\c_empty_box=\box26
\l_tmpa_box=\box27
\l_tmpb_box=\box28
\g_tmpa_box=\box29
\g_tmpb_box=\box30
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen112
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen113
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen114
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen115
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen116
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen117
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen118
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen119
\l__box_internal_box=\box31
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box32
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen120
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen121
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen122
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen123
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen124
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen125
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen126
\c_empty_coffin=\box33
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box34
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box35
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box36
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box37
\g_tmpa_coffin=\box38
\g_tmpb_coffin=\box39
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen127
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen128
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen129
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen130
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen131
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen132
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen133
\c__coffin_empty_coffin=\box40
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box41
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box42
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box43
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen134
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen135
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen136
\g__char_data_ior=\read1

(/home/maurizio/texmf/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3deprecation.def
File: l3deprecation.def 2019-04-06 v L3 Deprecated functions
))
(/home/maurizio/texmf/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2020-06-03 L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count176
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box44
))
(/home/maurizio/texmf/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty
Package: l3keys2e 2020-05-15 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
Package: pdfbase 2018/06/07 v0.24 driver independent access to low-level PDF fea
tures
\g_pbs_page_int=\count177


! Package pdfbase Error: Unknown package option `dvisvgm'.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              

l.257 \ProcessKeysOptions{pdfbase}


Packageoption 'dvisvgm' is unknown;
perhaps it is spelled incorrectly.


\g_pbs_oc_int=\count178
)
\@anim@box=\box45
\@anim@measbox=\box46
\@anim@tmpdima=\dimen137
\@anim@tmpdimb=\dimen138
\@anim@num=\count179
\@anim@curframe=\count180
\@anim@curframe@zb=\count181
\@anim@resizeflags=\count182
\@anim@skipfram=\count183
\@anim@mulframecnt=\count184
\@anim@@tmlnfile=\read2
\@anim@tmpcnt=\count185
\c@@anim@ltxcnt=\count186
\@anim@curlayer=\count187
\@anim@lineno=\count188
\@anim@curfield=\count189
\@anim@@resizeflags=\count190
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/media9/media9.sty
(/home/maurizio/texmf/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2020-05-15 L3 Experimental document command parser

(/home/maurizio/texmf/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse-generic.tex
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count191
\g__xparse_grabber_int=\count192
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count193
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count194
))
Package: media9 2018/06/07 v0.93 acrobat-9/X compatible media
\g_mix_pkgresizeflag_int=\count195

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ocgx2/ocgbase.sty
Package: ocgbase 2018/06/07 v0.14 support package for ocgx2.sty
\g_ocgbase_nd_int=\count196
)
\l_mix_poster_box=\box47
\g_mix_wd_dim=\dimen139
\g_mix_ht_dim=\dimen140
\g_mix_dp_dim=\dimen141
\g_mix_rmcnt_int=\count197
\l_mix_viewcnt_int=\count198
\g@mix@page@int=\count199

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                Use -1 not \c_minus_one deprecated on 2019-01-01.
l.347 \int_gset:Nn\g@mix@page@int{\c_minus_one}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
\__int_eval_end: 
l.347 \int_gset:Nn\g@mix@page@int{\c_minus_one}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

\g_mix_resizeflag_int=\count266
\l_mix_lineno_int=\count267
\l_mix_pbtn_box=\box48
\mix@btn@dim=\dimen142
\g_mix_mbtncnt_int=\count268
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen143
\Gin@req@width=\dimen144
)

LaTeX Warning: File `timeline.txt' already exists on the system.
               Not generating it from this source.

(./animate_example.aux)
\openout1 = animate_example.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box49


LaTeX Warning: Reference `anim@abspage0' on page 1 undefined on input line 20.


! Package animate Error: None of the files
(animate)                `exp_0.pdf',
(animate)                `exp_0.mps',
(animate)                `exp_0.png',
(animate)                `exp_0.jpg',
(animate)                `exp_0.jpeg',
(animate)                `exp_0.jp2',
(animate)                `exp_0.j2k' or
(animate)                `exp_0.jpx',
(animate)                could be found.
(animate)                Wrong file type? Mis-spelled file name?.

See the animate package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.20                ]{4}{exp_}{0}{8}

This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.

! Undefined control sequence.
\zap@finalspace #1 \@nil ->\unquote@name 
                                         {#1}
l.20                ]{4}{exp_}{0}{8}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .sty.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.20                ]{4}{exp_}{0}{8}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .sty.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.20                ]{4}{exp_}{0}{8}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                Use \str_if_eq:eeF not \str_if_eq_x:nnF deprecated on 2020-01-0
l.20                ]{4}{exp_}{0}{8}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
{
l.20                ]{4}{exp_}{0}{8}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! error:  (pdf backend): xforms cannot be used with a void box
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Did you pass the correct option? `\usepackage[dvisvgm]{animate}`  Also questions seeking debugging help (“**why isn't this code working?**”) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @HenriMenke Sorry, I extended my question, and provided essential details for reproducibility.

Comment: Have a look at this old question of mine https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404562/is-animate-package-compatible-with-htlatex, there might be useful information for you there

Comment: Your installation is broken.  You have installed `animate` into your local texmf tree but you don't have the correct versions of the dependencies.  Just update TeX Live as a whole to 2020.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks. Can you please point me out where you can deduce from the log above, that my installation is broken? It is just in the spirit of learning how to debug and read error messages more efficiently.

Comment: @maurizio In the very beginning it says `This is LuaTeX, Version 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2018)` indicating that your system is TeX Live 2018 and then later `Package: animate 2020/05/29`, which is clearly newer than TeX Live 2018.

Comment: @maurizio Also, the most recent `dvisvgm` version 2.9.1 is required. It is only available in TeXLive 2020.